# Upgrade from Symfony 3.4 to 4 : Errors when upgrading symfony

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, upgrade, symfony4

I try to upgrade my Symfony 3.4 project to Symfony 4. I cleaned my project of all deprecations but now when I want to upgrade, I have theses issues and I don't know how to do.

> COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update "symfony/*"
> --with-all-dependencies Loading composer repositories with package information
> Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is
> deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade
> to Composer 2. See
> https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/ Updating
> dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be
> resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - symfony/options-resolver v6.0.0 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.2.14) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.35
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.34
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.33
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.32
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.31
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.30
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.29
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.28
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.27
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.26
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.25
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.24
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.23
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.22
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.21
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.20
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.19
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.18
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.17
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.16
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.15
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.14
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.13
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.12
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.11
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.10
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.9
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.8
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.7
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.6
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.5
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.4
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.3
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.2
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.1
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.0
> - Conclusion: remove liip/imagine-bundle 2.7.3
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.11
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.10
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.9
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.8
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.7
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.6
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.5
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.4
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.3
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.2
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.1
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.0
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.12
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.11
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.10
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.9
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.8
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.7
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.6
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.5
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.4
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.3
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.2
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.1
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.0
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.1.13
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.1.12
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.1.11
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.1.10
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.1.9
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.1.8
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.1.7
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.1.6
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.1.5
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.1.4
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.1.3
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.1.2
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.1.1
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.1.0
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.15
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.14
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.13
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.12
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.11
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.10
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.9
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.8
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.7
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.6
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.5
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.4
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.3
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.2
> - Installation request for kriswallsmith/assetic (installed at v1.4.0) -> satisfiable by kriswallsmith/assetic[v1.4.0].
> - Installation request for liip/imagine-bundle (installed at 2.7.3, required as ^2.7) -> satisfiable by liip/imagine-bundle[2.7.3].
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.1
> - liip/imagine-bundle 2.7.3 requires symfony/options-resolver ^3.4|^4.4|^5.3|^6.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.4.49, v4.4.0,
> v4.4.1, v4.4.10, v4.4.11, v4.4.12, v4.4.13, v4.4.14, v4.4.15, v4.4.16,
> v4.4.17, v4.4.18, v4.4.19, v4.4.2, v4.4.20, v4.4.21, v4.4.22, v4.4.23,
> v4.4.24, v4.4.25, v4.4.26, v4.4.27, v4.4.28, v4.4.29, v4.4.3, v4.4.30,
> v4.4.31, v4.4.32, v4.4.33, v4.4.34, v4.4.35, v4.4.4, v4.4.5, v4.4.6,
> v4.4.7, v4.4.8, v4.4.9], symfony/options-resolver[v3.4.0, v3.4.1,
> v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16,
> v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23,
> v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.29, v3.4.3, v3.4.30,
> v3.4.31, v3.4.32, v3.4.33, v3.4.34, v3.4.35, v3.4.36, v3.4.37,
> v3.4.38, v3.4.39, v3.4.4, v3.4.40, v3.4.41, v3.4.42, v3.4.43, v3.4.44,
> v3.4.45, v3.4.46, v3.4.47, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9,
> v4.4.0, v4.4.1, v4.4.10, v4.4.11, v4.4.12, v4.4.13, v4.4.14, v4.4.15,
> v4.4.16, v4.4.17, v4.4.18, v4.4.19, v4.4.2, v4.4.20, v4.4.25, v4.4.27,
> v4.4.3, v4.4.30, v4.4.4, v4.4.5, v4.4.6, v4.4.7, v4.4.8, v4.4.9,
> v5.3.0, v5.3.4, v5.3.7, v5.4.0, v6.0.0].
> - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v4.0.0, v3.4.49].
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.10|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.11|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.12|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.13|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.14|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.15|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.16|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.17|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.18|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.19|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.20|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.21|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.22|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.23|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.24|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.25|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.26|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.27|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.28|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.29|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.30|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.31|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.32|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.33|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.34|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.35|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.36|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.37|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.38|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.39|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.40|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.41|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.42|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.43|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.44|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.45|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.46|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.47|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.6|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.7|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.8|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v3.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.10|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.11|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.12|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.13|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.14|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.15|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.16|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.17|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.18|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.19|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.20|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.25|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.27|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.30|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.6|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.7|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.8|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v5.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v5.3.4|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v5.3.7|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - don't install symfony/options-resolver v5.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.0
> - Installation request for symfony/symfony ^4 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.11, v4.0.12, v4.0.13,
> v4.0.14, v4.0.15, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7,
> v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13,
> v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9,
> v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4,
> v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v4.3.0, v4.3.1, v4.3.10,
> v4.3.11, v4.3.2, v4.3.3, v4.3.4, v4.3.5, v4.3.6, v4.3.7, v4.3.8,
> v4.3.9, v4.4.0, v4.4.1, v4.4.10, v4.4.11, v4.4.12, v4.4.13, v4.4.14,
> v4.4.15, v4.4.16, v4.4.17, v4.4.18, v4.4.19, v4.4.2, v4.4.20, v4.4.21,
> v4.4.22, v4.4.23, v4.4.24, v4.4.25, v4.4.26, v4.4.27, v4.4.28,
> v4.4.29, v4.4.3, v4.4.30, v4.4.31, v4.4.32, v4.4.33, v4.4.34, v4.4.35,
> v4.4.4, v4.4.5, v4.4.6, v4.4.7, v4.4.8, v4.4.9].

Here is my composer.json :

```
{
    "name": "beyonds/base",
    "license": "Beyonds",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "files": [
            "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
        ]
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@gitlab.com:alexandre.bru/admin-generator-bundle.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^5.5.9|>=7.0.8",
        "algolia/search-bundle": "4.0.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/inflector": "^1.4|^2.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "^1.5",
        "friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle": "^2",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^2.2",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0",
        "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "^9.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "lexik/translation-bundle": "^4.0",
        "liip/imagine-bundle": "^2.7",
        "nochso/html-compress-twig": "^2.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.4",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.6.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.23",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "^4",
        "thormeier/breadcrumb-bundle": "^2.2",
        "twig/extensions": "^1.2",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyonds/cms-generator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^6.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "component-dir": "web/assets"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": null,
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": "true"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear: The composer.json already requires Symfony 4!? If you edited that manually, you could just discard the lock file and run `composer install`.

Comment: Yes, I just change Symfony version from ^3.4 to ^4 and execute composer update with dependencies

Comment: That's not the way I'd do it. Rather, I'd use `composer require ...` to upgrade. Also, there's an elephant in this room: "composer Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. ", so run `composer self-update`.

Comment: Yes but composer-plugin-api need to be on 1.0.0 and not 2.0.0 :
  
```Problem 1
    - helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle[9.3, ..., 9.3.2] require robloach/component-installer ~0.2 -> satisfiable by robloach/component-installer[0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3].
    - robloach/component-installer 0.2.0 requires composer-plugin-api 1.0.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
    - robloach/component-installer[0.2.1, ..., 0.2.3] require composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.```

Comment: So, there is one package holding you back. Check if you really need it. Check if it really depends on that plugin API version. Check for bug tickets/pull requests fixing this. It may well be that this is exactly what's keeping you from being able to upgrade Symfony.

Comment: "Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2." - what have you tried to resolve this problem? Also, `helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle` in v9 is pretty outdated

Comment: When composer blows up on me I like to just create a new symfony project and then use composer require to load each additional package one by one.  This generally helps to narrow down the problem packages.  You should be using composer 2 and you will need a minimum of PHP 7.1.3.

Comment: Thanks for all your answer, I remove composer.lock and execute composer install and it's working. I'm working now of some fixes.

Answer (score 1):

Skipping through the list of requirements, this might be the one to blame:

- `helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle` in v9 requires `robloach/component-installer`
- `robloach/component-installer` in any version requires `kriswallsmith/assetic`
- `kriswallsmith/assetic` in the latest version requires components from Symfony 3 and is **not** compatible with Symfony 4

---

You should update `helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle` to any later version to get rid of the dependency on `robloach/component-installer`